# How to write a $match on a $lookup document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two MongoDB collections that look like this:

```
Products      Specials
----------    ----------
_id           _id
name          product_id
country       zip
price         percent_discount
              out_of_stock
```

I'm using GraphQL as well so I wrote up an aggregate pipeline that returns the data in this structure:

```
specials {
  _id
  product {
    _id
    name
    country
    price
  }
  zip
  percent_discount
  out_of_stock
}
```

This aggregate pipeline I wrote works great and looks like this:

```
let response = await Specials.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'products',
            localField: 'product_id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'product'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$product'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            zip: zip
        }
    }
])

return response;
```

Now I'm trying to add a filter into this. The filter should match the name or country in the product collection preferably with regex. So I tried writing something like this but it's yielding over 8000 results when there should be only 2-3:

```
let response = await Specials.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { zip: zip }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "products",
            let: { product_id: "$product_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                {
                                    _id: "$$product_id"
                                },
                                {
                                    $or: [
                                        {
                                            name: filter
                                        },
                                        {
                                            country: filter
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "product"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$product"
    }
])
```

Comment: On basic thing you're missing here is you've created local variable `product_id` but you're not matching it against `_id` of `products` collection !! Isn't that needed ?

Comment: that is correct! thanks for pointing that out. How should I go about that because localField/foreignField can't be used with pipeline

Comment: Try this :: `{
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: ["$$product_id", "$_id"],
          {  $or: [
              {
                $eq: ["$name", ''],
              },
              {
                $eq: ["$country", ''],
              },
            ]
          }
    }
  }`

Comment: it's throwing an error "An object representing an expression must have exactly one field".. I'm playing around with the formatting

Comment: don’t have access to lappy, wrap both ‘$eq’ and ‘$or’ in ‘$and’..

Comment: ah okay that worked great! and it makes total sense. If you'd like to answer the question with the correct pipeline I can accept it or I could just write the answer myself and @ you

Comment: one question tho.. do you know if there a way to use $regex within $eq? like $eq: ["$country", $regex: filter ] or something

Comment: I remember long back I did try a small hack to make achieve something similar, but unfortunately couldn't recollect it now. but what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Basically I want my filter to be a regex. In my project Italy will yield certain results because it's a filter that will create matching records. But ita will not. If it was $regex: ita then it would still match. But I keep getting an error in my pipeline that $regex is not an expression

Comment: Ok I'm a bit confused ! If we forget about regex thing for a while, Since you're doing `$eq: ["$$product_id", "$_id"]` , As `_id` will be unique in `products`, So for a special you'll either have 1 product or nothing (nothing when if all two conditions in `$or` fails), Is that correct ? It means this `$or` is an additional match criteria to initial `$eq: ["$$product_id", "$_id"]` ?

Comment: regex aside the solution you gave me is working great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the following solution that I was able to get working:

```
let response = await Specials.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "products",
            let: { product_id: "$product_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $and: [
                            {
                                $or: [
                                    {
                                        name: { $regex: filter }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        country: { $regex: filter }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                $expr: {
                                    $eq: ["$$product_id", "$_id"]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "product"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$product"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {
                    zip: zip
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])

return response;
```

** Updated with the working $regex implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mongo version 4.2+ you can use [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/)

```
let response = await Specials.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "products",
            let: { product_id: "$product_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                       $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                {
                                    $eq: ["$$product_id", "$_id"]
                                },
                                {
                                    $or: [
                                        {
                                            $regexMatch: { input: "$name", regex: filterRegex }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            $regexMatch: { input: "$country", regex: filterRegex }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "product"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$product"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {
                    zip: zip
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])

return response;
```

Comment: Throwing "Unrecognized expression '$regexMatch'" error. In my package.json my Mongodb version is 3.5.8. I ran npm install --save mongodb@latest and that's the package is installed

Comment: Well 3.5 < 4.2 so it makes sense.

Comment: I know. I wasn't able to install the latest version through npm I miscommunicated that. I was however able to work out a solution with $regex. Thank you for taking time to write me a solution with the latest version though I will certainly be using $regexMatch in the future

Comment: Just to clarify, install mongo through npm installs the nodejs driver, the actual Mongo version is to be installed by other means using stuff like `brew`, `yum` etc...